# Efficient isolation critereon

Tags: python, search, combinatorics, astronomy

The project I'm working on involves reading and analyzing a huge data set (Illustris 1 Dark, about 4,000,000 dark matter halos). In order to get better results, I want to impose an isolation criteria as follows:

> Only keep those halos that are the biggest in the 2D circle of radius 300kpc, and get rid of the other halos in that circle

Now, the current implementation I have has run time in O(n^2), which means the code could take *days* to finish. I really want to do better but can't figure out how. This is what I have so far:

**Function for returning a list of neighbors of Group1**

```
def neighbors(Group1, Radius):
    Neighbors = []
    for Group2 in Groups:
        if Distance_2D(Group1, Group2) < Radius:
            Neighbors.append(Group2)
    return Neighbors
```

**Function for returning the biggest group given a list of neighbors**

```
def biggest(Neighbors):
    Biggest = Neighbors[0]
    for N in Neighbors:
        if N.mass > Biggest.mass:
            Biggest = N
    return Biggest
```

**Putting it all together**

```
for Group in Groups:
    Neighbors = neighbors(Group, 300)
    if not Group == Biggest(Neighbors):
        Groups.remove(Group)
    else:
        Groups.remove(Neighbors)
        Groups.append(Group)
```

After the for-loop, Groups should be a list of halos that are the largest within their 300kpc radius.

I also know that removing something from a list while iterating the same list is not good practice, so if your hint/answer takes care of that, that would be great!

Thank you all in advance :)

Comment: What is the object `Group`?

Comment: Group is the dark matter halo. It contains information like the halo's position and mass.

Comment: Raw data set is available at http://www.illustris-project.org/data/  Although it's a 202GB data file :-(

Comment: Yep that's it. Although I'm only working on the z = 0 catalog, which is around 4GB, so not so bad.

Comment: It looks like "300kpc", in context, means 300,000 parsecs, but reduced to an angle that's 83.3 degrees, which seems... kinda big. Can you clarify what the desired radius angle is?

Comment: 360? I'm not sure how you made that conversion from 300kpc to degrees, but all I want is the radius of the circle to be 300kpc (forgive me if have some major misunderstanding!)

Comment: The misunderstanding, on my part at least, is "what is a kpc", and my conversion from distance (parsecs) to degrees was based on 1 parsec == 1 arc-second == 1/3600 degree.

Comment: Oh I see what you're saying. In this context parsec is the unit of distance. 1pc = 3.086 × 10^13 kilometers

Comment: Ah! So you want 3d distance, not 2d. That makes more sense.

Comment: Oh, that is not what I meant. I still need the 2D distance (in Y and Z coordinates, since X is my LOS axis.

Answer (score 0):

Halo with the largest mass will be in a group. Halos that are closer than radius to the largest halo will not be in a group. With that outline of algorithm is to:

```
result = []
for h in sorted(halos, key=lambda h: h.mass, reverse=True):
  if all(distance(h.position, x.position) > 300 for x in result):
    result.append(h)
```

Checking of distance is tricky.

- If expected size of result list is small, than each halo is checked with that small list. That algorithm has complexity `O(n*log(n) + n * |result set|)`.
- If expected size of result list is large, that [space partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning) can help.

Like:

```
result = []
sp = SpacePartition()  # Some space partition
for h in sorted(halos, key=lambda h: h.mass, reverse=True):
  if not sp.has_point_close(h.position, 300):
    result.append(h)
    sp.add(h.position)
```

That algorithm has complexity `O(n*log(n))`, since checking and adding to partition is of `log(n)`.